# Tools to create HTML-Based Windows UI in C++

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface

I'm looking for suggestions on technologies to design a windows UI that's powered by HTML. I've run across [HTMLayout](http://www.terrainformatica.com/htmlayout/main.whtm) which seems pretty good if not perhaps a bit limited. Are there any other technologies that would provide a good platform for creating an application UI based on HTML?

Comment: To those voting to close -- if this is not a real question, I'll eat my hat. (It might not be the smartest thing to do, but it's certainly a question!)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use [chromiumembedded](http://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/). You get the power of Google's Chrome in your application.

Evernote used CEF (Chromium Embedded Framework) when they moved from [C# back to C++](http://www.itwriting.com/blog/3385-lessons-from-evernotes-flight-from-net.html/).

Unlike HTMLayout, CEF has a permissive license, which allows usage in commercial applications without paying royalties. The drawback would be the huge binary size.

Comment: Just for the note: HTMLayout is free for commercial and non-commercial use.

Answer (score 3):

[Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/products/) has the ability to use CSS to layout ui and [some other cool things](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qdeclarativeexamples.html). [MSHTML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741317%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) namespace and COM interfaces allow for some ui styles as well. That's all I know of off the top of my head for C++

[Windows 8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_8) when released will provide some sort of API using HTML5 and JavaScript for tile based applications in the start screen.